# Is it possible to use an Android SDK on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: java, android, linux, raspberry-pi, arm

I want to start off by saying that I am not a Java developer. I've never ventured outside of Windows and C#. But for my current goal neither C# nor Windows is adequate.

I am planning on using RPI4. The problem is the hardware I would like to integrate only provides SDK for Linux(x64 x32) and Android 4.0+. Now RPI4 has a an arm based CPU so using the linux sdk is out of the question. But the android SDK is for ARM based devices and it also supports arm64-v8a which would be the RPI.

So my question is whether I could use these .so and .jar files to make something on the RPI or am I out of luck?

Comment: Simple answer no.Not even with a docker.You could however use java jar and so files not dependent on android platform

Comment: You have mentioned SDK so it means wanted to build app .. i think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .so file for Android 4.0 onwards, you can *potentially* use that by running Android on a Raspberry Pi. This isn't terribly hard, but you need a separate SD-card to boot from; running Android under Raspberry Pi OS seems to be an unsolved problem.

There's an answer about running Android on Raspberry Pi over on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229784/is-it-possible-to-run-android-on-a-raspberry-pi).